# androidplot: insert logo on graph

Tags: android, bitmap, androidplot

I would like to add a logo, or generally one or more bitmap,on androidplot graph. 
I think the solution is to transform the  androidplot graph as a bitmap and then add the other bitmap above. 
But this solution is not good because convert the graph into bitmap i lose the quality of the graph. 
The ideal would be not convert into bitmap. can someone help me? 
thanks

Comment: Are you using it like this??? I mean in xml => 

`<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/xyplot"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        title="Income / Expenditure Chart [ Year 2012 ]"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **FrameLayout** for this purpose,

`Add your graph xml code in FrameLayout and Add another ImageView or Button or what ever you like in FrameLayout`

I am placing an ImageView in the bottom right corner of the Graph. You can change it.

1. **XML Code**:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/frame_for_graph"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

           <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
                   android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   title="Stats" />

           <ImageView
                   android:id="@+id/iv_Logo"
                   android:layout_width="40dp"
                   android:layout_height="40dp"
                   android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                   android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. **Java Code for Logo**:

   ```
   ImageView logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_Logo);

   logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logo Clicked",
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           //Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("YOUR COMPANY URL"));
           //startActivity(browserIntent);
       }
   });
   ```

## **SnapShot:**

[image: Snap]